# What's are the issues ORM are trying to solve that a Database does not?

Tags: c#, orm, ado.net

I work in a team with 15 developers in a large enterprise. We deal with many tables that have millions of records on the OLTP database. The data warehouse database is much larger.

We're embarking on a new system that needs to be developed that will be going against a very similar sized database. Each one of us is highly proficient and very comfortable with SQL, stored procedure etc. examining execution plans, defining the correct indexes etc. We're all also very comfortable in .NET C# and ASP.NET.

However we've each been looking into ORMs independently and none of us is able to understand the real problem they solve. On the contrary, what we do see is the performance issues people have and all the tweaks that need to be done in order to accommodate what the lack.

Another aspect that seems be that people use ORMs so as not to have to get their hands dirty with dealing with the database and SQL etc., but in fact it seems that you can't escape it for too long, especially when it comes to performance.

So my question is, what are the problems ORMs solve (or attempt to solve).

I should note that we have about 900 tables and over 2000 stored procedure in our OLTP database and our data layer is auto generated off of our stored procedures and we use ADO.NET core currently.

Comment: I would hate to maintain that, 900 tables is ridiculous... Sounds like a fail application. (opinion)

Comment: 2000 stored procedures?  Auto generated?  Double fail.  (Opinion.)  You don't need an ORM.

Comment: 2000 auto-generated SPs. Generate some client-side code to go with it and that *is* an ORM.

Comment: Funny how all of you seem to have a warped concept of an application. 900 tables is a small project in my experience. What is your experience? 9?

Comment: @duffymo, the stored procedures and tables are hard made, the data access layer is generated code based off of the stored procedures. That's clearly stated in my post. If you don't have any value to add please don't post comments.

Comment: I've never seen a database with more than 200 tables, 1000+ SPs, that was well designed, maintainable, or have and performent without throwing hardware at it. The application I work on has around 400 tables, and SPs are just not maintainable. You add a column, then theres 424234523324 stored procs to update. Altho it was my 'opinion', in my 'experience', anymore than 50 tables in a single database... and your application is rubbish.

Comment: 900 tables may or may not be a large project, depending on how normalized your schema is.  Relational databases where I am have many terabytes of data, so I think that's worthy.  I think I'm adding value, Jackie.  If you're too sensitive, don't post your questions in public.  Grow a skin, please.

Comment: @Phil just because you've never encountered something doesn't mean it's bad and besides where do you get 50 from? Pull it out of a hat? Whether the stored procedures are in one database or 20 if something changes you've got to change other things. I mean they've changed for a reason. Stored procedure do provide an abstraction. For example if you changed the way data is laid out, say it went to two tables to 3. the storped proc can still provide the same projection on the data and the rest of the system is not impacted.

Comment: @duffymo, normalized to 3rd normal form mostly. But not beyond. Don't see why I'm justifying any of this. My question has nothing to do with data modeling on design. You're not adding value since you're not answering the question and are quick to judge.

Comment: I did answer the question: you don't need ORM.  Other people seem to be saying the same thing.  You get to judge the value.  Sounds more like you don't care for how I'm saying it.  Next....

Comment: @duffymo, I'm sorry, I don't seem the understand the lingo people seem to use.

Comment: Stored procedure, hard coded SQL projects are a nightmare to maintain. Sometimes it's desirable to adjust the structure of the database. If you are open to the concept someone else may be able to improve on your initial design or adjust it to suit business needs you will never allow 2000 stored procedures to accumulate. That's what most people would call a "rat's nest", but a handful of stored procedures is maintainable. Another side effect is often SPROCs are created for a certain page. When the page is gone the SPROC remains unless you take the time to ensure it's ok to delete.

Answer (score 4):

ORMs attempt to solve the [object-relational impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch).

That is, since relational databases are ... relational in nature, the data modeling used for them is very different from the type of modeling you would use in OOP.

This difference is known as the "object-relational impedance mismatch". ORMs try to let you use OOP without consideration of how the database is modeled.

Comment: This is a good answer.  I'd add that relational databases and SQL are set-based in nature; objects, by definition, are individual things, not set-based.  I think that's a big contributor to the OR impedance.

Comment: @duffymo - Indeed. The fact that you query a DB and traverse an object graph are very different in nature as well also contributes to the issue.

Comment: @Oded I understand this statement. You've got a collection of objects. How you got them is not relevant, and once you have them there is no difference, correct? Or am I not getting it?

Comment: @Jackie Kirby - that's part of it. That ORMs afford ["persistence ignorance"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx#id0420053) is irrelevant. What is relevant is that when in code you do `myObj.myCollection`, this is not how you would get `myCollection` data from the database - ORMs hide this difference.

Comment: So that's the big reason? Our business layer has no idea about the persistence nor any idea about the relationships. Since our sps give us the abstraction we require.

Comment: @Jackie Kirby - The big reason is to (try to) allow OOP to be OOP and databases be databases. They are very different paradigms and don't quite work smoothly together. ORMs try to bridge the gap.

Comment: It's pretty well known that relational databases performance degrades as the number of JOINs increases.  The rule of thumb that I've heard is no more than seven JOINs.  If you have deep object graphs, which are common for geometric data, you're likely to prefer an object database like db4o.

Answer (score 4):

ORMs are for object-oriented people who think that everything works better when they're in objects.  They have their best opportunity on projects where OO skills are stronger and more plentiful than SQL and relational databases.

If you're writing in an object-oriented language you'll have to deal with objects at one time or another.  Whether you use ORM or not, you'll have to get that data out of the tables and into objects on the middle tier so you can work with them.  ORM can help you with the tedium of mapping.  But it's not 100% necessary.  It's a choice like any other.

Don't make the mistake of writing a client/server app with objects.  If your objects are little more than carriers of data from the database to the client, I'd say you're doing something wrong.  There's value in encapsulating behavior in objects where it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think, as with all these things, the answer to the question of whether you should use an ORM is 'it depends'.  In a lot of cases, people may be writing relatively simple applications with relatively small databases in the background.

In these cases, an ORM makes sense, as it allows for easy maintenance (adding a column is a one place change to have it ripple through you application) and quick turnaround.

However, if you are dealing with very large databases and complex data manipulation, then an ORM is possibly not for you.  That said, tables with millions of rows should still not be a problem for an ORM, it all depends on how you return and use the data - a well structured database should allow for reasonable performance.

In you case, you can't see the benefit, as it's maybe not suitable to your application - it is for some others.

---

BTW - what you describe in your question - stored procedures used to generate classes used in your business layer.  This is essentially what a good ORM mapper is - get away from writing the boiler-plate data access code and work on the business logic.

Comment: @Jackie Kirby - for me that's a large part of it - there's more to it than that, but for me, it gives me more time in my day actually adding value (proper business logic) rather than typing reams of conn = new connection() type code.

Answer (score 0):

Very good question. It depends on what you are building.

If you have complex object structures (objects with many relationships and encapsulated objects) and you manipulate these objects inside memory before committing the transaction, it is much easier to use ORM like Hibernate, because you don't need to worry about SQL, Caching, Just-In-Time object loading, etc. As a bonus feature you will get pretty good database independence.

If you have very simple objects in your application, without much functionality/methods, you can of course use plain SQL/DB connection. However I would recommend you to use ORM anyway, because you will be database independent, more portable and you will be ready to grow, when your system will need just-in-time object loading, long transactions (with caching), etc.

I have worked with many persistence frameworks in my life and I would recommend Hibernate.

Answer (score -1):

In short, its really trying to make the DB appear as objects to the programmer, so the programmer can be more productive. The only benefit (besides assisting dev laziness) is that the columns mapped to classes are strongly typed - no more trying to fetch a string into an integer variable!

From all the years of ORM libraries that have come and gone, they all seem (IMHO) to be just another programmer toy. Ultimately, its another abstraction that might help you when you start out, or when writing small apps. My opinon here is that once you learn a god way of accessing the DB, you might as well continue to use that way rather than learn many ways of doing the same task - I always feel more productive being a specialist, but that could just be me.

The tools required to create and maintain the mapping, generate the classes, etc are another nuisance. In this regard a built-in framework (eg ruby on rails' ActiveRecord approach) is much better.

Performance can be an issue, as can the sql that is generated at the back end - you will nearly alwas be fetching much more data than you needed when using an ORM compared to the small SQL statements you might otherwise write.

The strong typing is good though, and I would praise ORMs for that.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to fetch more data than you need, for instance in Linq Based ORM (LinqToSQL, Entity Framework, Nhibernate) you can just select the columns that you need instead of fetching a whol row. Also remember that stackoverflow is written with LinqToSQL as Jeff has stated: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Comment: @Carlos, in what layer are you using your linq to SQL? Why should anything outside of the database know the structure of your tables and their relationships? Performance of ORMs is in fact a problem (from what I've read) and primarily due to selecting all columns. Linq2SQL is not an ORM really is it. EntityFramewrok and NHibernate are